# 405 on POST request, unsupported method is GET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I'm having a bit of a fight with the following problem, I have a ASP.NET Web API, when making one of the POST requests on the development machine, I get the expected output from it, but after deploying it on IIS, I get the response

```
"message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
```

The input I give via Postman looks as follows
[image]

I've read the following post, but I didn't get much out of it after poking around in IIS for a while.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

Start of the method looks as follows

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("something/CandidatePersonal")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostCandidatePersonal(CanPersonal apiPostInput)
```

and it returns an OK statement considering everything goes well.

Comment: Are you using some sort of virtual path? Just to note: using the `/` in `/CandidatePersonal` could overwrite base paths defined in your startup file or even act weird with IIS virtual paths. Most of the time you should enter it without a leading slash: `[Route("CandidatePersonal")]`

Comment: It could be a `CORS` issue. Decorate your `Controller` with: `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")] ` and in your `webapi.config`: `config.EnableCors();`

Comment: @Silvermind I simplified it to not expose any exact path since this is a company project, but there is indeed a full path and not just /

Comment: @RahulSharma That sadly was not the problem, exact same error still.

Comment: @NiceDevelopmentq Umm, well it could because of your base url that you call for the `API`. Try adding `WWW` to the url for calling the `API`

Comment: @RahulSharma Nope, we haven't set that prefix up anyways in IIS, but it was worth a shot! :D

Comment: @NiceDevelopmentq Did you try adding `[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]` on your `API` method?

Comment: @RahulSharma I had originally only added "POST" into AcceptVerbs, don't know why I didn't think of GET as well, but that seemed to fix it! Thanks a lot :D Please post it as an answer so I can flag it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your scenario, you need to add `[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]` on your `API` method.